# How can I get the default gcc compiler back?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I can't compile ("make") anything at the moment. It all ends with the following:

```
as: unrecognized option '--64'
```

So I searched for the cause and found that

```
gcc -version
```

gave me this:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20060728 (prerelease) (TIGCC 4.1.2-pre9)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Ah, yes, I did install TIGCC at some point (it's used to cross-compile C programs for the TI calculators). I really don't need it anymore, but I can't find how I'm supposed to reconfigure gcc back to normal. I tried doing

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc binutils
```

but it doesn't change anything. I could try with --purge, but that would require me to uninstall a lot of other packages (like graphic drivers x_x). Anything simpler I should try? :)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
type -a
```

returned two paths for gcc, one of which was the one from tigcc. I deleted that file and now `gcc --version` shows the correct one (4.8.2). However, I still get the same errors! :(

```
$ as --version
GNU assembler 2.16.1
Copyright 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License.  This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `m68k-coff'.
```

I have no idea what `m68k-coff` is/means... but I'm on a AMD x64 system! ?

Comment: m68k-coff is a cross compiler for win

Comment: What does `dpkg -S $(which as)` say?

Comment: dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /home/USER/bin/as

Comment: but 'which as' returns 'home/USER/bin/as' which looks suspicious to me... the gcc from TIGCC was also in there... should I just delete that as well?

Comment: @muru so the binaries were in home, which explains why it wasn't part of the alternatives setup; but I'm still unsure about what just happened here.

Comment: @chaskes I'm guessing OP manually installed a few tools (configure, make, make install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the quite improbable case that anyone has the same problems and doesn't mind getting rid of TIGCC, I had to delete `/home/USER/bin/gcc` and `/home/USER/bin/as`.

When issuing

```
$ type -a
/usr/bin/gcc
/home/USER/bin/gcc
```

and same thing for `as`.